# Domain activation failed on aws amplify

Tags: web-hosting, dns, amazon-aws

I am trying to bind my domain hosted on godaddy with my web app hosted on amplify. I have followed the instruction, added the CNAMEs to godaddy as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

After a few days, my ssl configuration is verified, but the domain activation is failed.

[image]

I am not sure what was wrong, I went to check up the DNS, seems my app.xyz.com has been resolved?

[image]

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out it is because when adding the CNAME to enable the https, I missed the ending period in the name.
Now. my custom domain is available. But it still doesn't work, it says 404.